# How to retrieve data from multiple tables that may or may not have values in common

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have looked through everywhere on web and stack overflow but unable to find on how to perform the task as below:

```
var query = (
    from r1 in db.table1
    where r1.Timestamp == date.ToUniversalTime()
    from r2 in db.table2
        .Where(p => p.Timestamp == date.ToUniversalTime())
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        prod = r1.Value1,
        prod2 = r2.Value1
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The two tables are not linked to each other but I want to get the data from both the tables in just one query, this is just a sample but in real I have many columns to get the data from.

Apologies if this question is a duplicate but I didnt really find an answer when I searched.

in SQL we can do something like this.

```
Select r1.*,r2.* from table1 r1, table2 r2
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to do a cross join? What's wrong with your LINQ query? This should work. A `from a in TableA from b in TableB` translates effectively to a cross join in SQL.

Comment: May be i was not very clear, let suppose if i have 2 columns in table1 (value1,value2), and 3columns in table2 (value1,value2,value3). there could be only one value in the both the table for a particular time. I want to write a query in such a way that even if one of the table does not have the data, the other table should return the data based on the query. Is it possible? In my query above, I do not get anything from the second table, if the first table does not have anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure why your question title says “without join”, since judging from your SQL you clearly *do* want a join. But anyway.

I’m going by the comment you posted to your question. It seems that you want one row returned for every unique date value that comes up in both tables, right?

In that case, I would use `Union`:

```
var dates = db.Table1.Select(t => t.Timestamp).Union(
            db.Table2.Select(t => t.Timestamp));
```

Next you can turn each timestamp into a full row with all the information:

```
var result = dates.Select(date => new
{
    Table1Info = db.Table1.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Timestamp == date),
    Table2Info = db.Table2.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Timestamp == date)
});
```

Remember that even if you write it as two variables like this, it is still run as a single query when you evaluate it (using `foreach`, for example). That makes the code quite a bit more readable.

If this is not what you wanted, I recommend that you edit your question instead of adding more comments. Right now all the question actually asks is “what is the LINQ equivalent of `select r1.*, r2.* from table1 r1, table2 r2`?” and the answer to that has already been posted.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you (where db is you linq data context):

```
var result= (
        from r1 in db.table1.Where(a=>a.Timestamp==date.ToUniversalTime())
        from r2 in db.table2.Where(a=>a.Timestamp==date.ToUniversalTime())
        select new
        {
            r1,
            r2
        }
    );
```

This sql:

```
Select r1.*,r2.* from table1 r1, table2 r2
```

Comment: but there is a condition as well that i need to check for the time in both the table

Comment: above query create cross join between r1 and r2 tables see SQL query for the LINQ query.